# Azure Communication Services with Flutter

Tags: flutter, azure, azure-communication-services

Good day! I am planning make a Flutter application that uses Azure Communication Service for chat and video calls/conferencing. I cannot find any from the web, like tutorials or documentations on how to do this. Is there anyone who can help me finding this?[image]

The I am not quite following the tutorial here since there is nothing for flutter or dart. However, I already installed the AzureCommunicationChat in the iOS using the command line.

[image]

My problem is that how can I use this to build my flutter project.
I already searched in pub.dev for a flutter package but there is nothing. I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no package from Azure or from other sources to integrate Azure communication services into Flutter. You can integrate Azure communication services to Flutter by doing the native implementation. You can configure native implementation by following the azure documentation and write a platfrom channel and starting the call using the platform channel.

Follow the below link to know how to set up azure communication services.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/voice-video-calling/getting-started-with-calling?tabs=uwp&pivots=platform-android

For ui azure is giving the sample you can use it. I have mentioned the link below.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/samples/calling-hero-sample?pivots=platform-android